# Unsetting View permission for Layout

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

In Liferay 7, to set the VIEW permission for a layout, I have used this method:

`resourcePermissionLocalService.setResourcePermissions(companyId, LAYOUT_CLASS_NAME, scope, primKey, roleId, ActionKeys.VIEW)`;

My question is: How to **unset** `VIEW` permission so that the roleId cannot view the layout?

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.java#L756 ?

Comment: You can use `resourcePermissionLocalService.removeResourcePermission` to unset / remove the desired permission.

Comment: Also, it is better to use service method(s) from `*Util`.

Comment: In Liferay 7, We use method from OSGI service and *Util Class method as used for backword compatibility.